# Scraping data from currently opened website in excel and delete last search result excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to scrape company data from web page www.bizi.si. It is working ok, but when I change company in web site BIZI I get in excel the same result of a previous search (REPROMAT d.o.o. and address), but I want to be result (CERJAK d.o.o. and address). I must close and open excel to extract different company data. I wish I could scrape data from different companies without closing excel file. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sub CompanyData()

Dim html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, nodes As Object

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NAROČILO")
Set html = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.bizi.si/iskanje?q=" & Application.EncodeURL(ws.Range("A1").Value), False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll("td.item")

    With ws
        .Range("A4").Value = nodes.Item(0).FirstChild.innerText
        .Range("A5").Value = nodes.Item(1).innerText
        .Range("B6").Value = nodes.Item(3).innerText
    End With

    .Open "GET", html.querySelector("[id$=linkCompany]").href, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    ws.Range("A3") = html.querySelector("#ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMainCol_CompanySPLPreview1_labTitlePRS").innerText
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Provided I change the value in cell A1 it runs just fine

Comment: I is working ok now. Looks like it was a problem in the laptop itself. Too much work. :) Thank you. QHarr

Comment: No worries. Glad it solved.

Comment: QHarr I need help with the same issue - they changed website I now i have the same problems

Answer (score 0):

Problem was - missing sentence .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

Sub CompanyData()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, nodes As Object

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NAROČILO")
Set html = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.bizi.si/iskanje?q=" & Application.EncodeURL(ws.Range("A1").Value), False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll("td.item")

    With ws
        .Range("A4").Value = nodes.Item(0).FirstChild.innerText
        .Range("A5").Value = nodes.Item(1).innerText
        .Range("B6").Value = nodes.Item(3).innerText
    End With

    .Open "GET", html.querySelector("[id$=linkCompany]").href, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    ws.Range("A3") = html.querySelector("#ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMainCol_CompanySPLPreview1_labTitlePRS").innerText
End With
```

End Sub